# How to prefer one library location vs. another one with Clang?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, clang

I have a system-wide `libc++.so` in `/usr/lib64`. I want to link my binary against another `libc++.so` which is located somewhere else, say, in `$HOME/.local/lib`. Also, I want to be able to find all other libraries the same way as before, assuming that `$HOME/.local/lib` contains only `libc++.so`.

I'm trying to do this like: `clang++ -L$HOME/.local/lib -lc++`, but the compiler still links against `/usr/lib64/libc++.so`.

---

How to force the compiler (or linker) to link against a specific library location?

Answer (score 1):

`-L` adds the directory to the search path used by the linker. This has no effect on the search paths used at runtime. At runtime, the search paths, in order, are:

1. The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. `rpath` specified in the executable
3. System library path

While you can achieve what you want by specifying the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib`, it is a bad solution since it modifies the search paths of all executables. Specifying the `rpath` is a much cleaner solution since it only affects the behaviour of your executable. You can do this through the linker option of your toolchain, which is likely `-rpath`. So the command would be `clang++ -rpath $HOME/.local/lib -lc++`.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I don't want to hardcode rpath or to affect the runtime behavior. I want to specify the exact library to the linker, so it use it - and not another one with the same name - when doing the linkage.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't using this lib to link? Perhaps add some details to the question showing how you diagnosed the issue and in what way the behaviour is different from what you expected.